# Oracle index barely speeding up aggregate calculations

Tags: database, oracle, indexing

I created a table with two columns, a and b. Column a is simply the numbers 1 to 100 million. Column b is a random integer between 0 and 999 inclusive. I wanted to use this table to check how indexes improve calculations. So I checked the following:

```
select count(*) from my_table where b = 332 

select avg(a) from my_table where b = 387
```

The 332 and 387 are just random integers, I wanted to make sure it wasn't caching anything so I switched it.

Then I created an index:

```
create bitmap index myindx1 on my_table (b);
commit;
```

This brought the count(*) down from 14 seconds to 75 milliseconds, success!

But the avg(a) didn't fare so well. It actually got worse, going from 8 seconds to 10 seconds. I didn't test this a ton of times and based on the plans it looks to be a fluke, but at the very least it doesn't seem to be doing much better as I expected it to.

The explain plan without the index looks like:

[image: explain plan without index]

The explain plan with the index looks like:

[image: explain plan with index]

So it looks like it's helping a bit, but is it really that much more expensive to average numbers than count them? And way more expensive to average numbers than to do a full table scan? I thought this index would cut my query into a fraction of the original cost rather than just shaving off a little bit of time. Is there something else I can do to speed up this query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the way you set up your test - it isn't realistic and it is bad for indexes.

First: you have just two integer columns in your table, so each row is VERY small.  So, Oracle can fit a lot of rows into each database block -- like a few *thousand* rows per block.

Second: you created your indexed data *randomly*, with values between 0 and 999.

Put those two facts together and what can we guess?  Answer: just about *every single database block* is going to have at least one row with any given value of column `B`.

So, no matter what value of `B` you look for, you are going to wind up reading every block in your table one at a time (i.e.: "sequential read").

Compare that to the plan using no index -- a full table scan -- where Oracle will still read every single block, but it will read them several blocks at a time (i.e., "scattered read").

No wonder your index didn't help.

If you want a better test, add column `C` to your test table that is just a string of 200-300 characters (e.g., "XXXXXXXXX...").  This will reduce the number of rows per block to a more realistic value and you should see better gains from your index.

LAST NOTE: be very careful about using a `BITMAP` index.  They are all but unusable on tables that have any sort of DML (insert, update, deleting) happening on them!  Read all about them before using one!

#### UPDATE

Clarification on this:

> > So it looks like it's helping a bit, but is it really that much more expensive to average numbers than count them? And way more expensive to average numbers than to do a full table scan?

The reason your index helped your `COUNT(*)` query is that the index by itself will tell Oracle how many rows meet the condition `B=332`, so it does not need to read the table blocks and therefore does not suffer from the problem I described above (i.e., reading each table block one-by-one).

It's not that `COUNT()` is "faster" then `AVG()`.  It's just that, in your test, the `COUNT` could be computed using only the index, whereas `AVG` needed information from the table.

Comment: Interesting, this all makes sense. To clarify, I simplified my problem since my actual problem uses confidential data for my job. My problem actually involves some metrics cut by a few factors. Basically the problem is there are too many factor combinations to simply pre-aggregate every possible average, but I also don't want the user to have to wait minutes every time they change the factors.

The reason I did a bitmap index was my understanding was they were better on columns with low relative numbers of distinct values and where there wasn't a ton of writing/updating.

Comment: For my money, replace "not a ton of writing/updating" with "no writing/updating" (outside of, at most, a single ETL process).  You should start with a standard (B*tree) index and see how performance is.  There are other ways to further improve performance besides bitmap indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Bitmap indexes should not be used in OTLP systems. Their maintenance cost is too high.

IHMO pure B*tree index will be  enough. INDEX RANGE SCAN traverses from root to leftest leaf heaving value "332" and then iterates from left to right visiting all leaves having the same value of "B". This is all you want.

If you want to speed it up even more you can create so called covering index. Put both column "B" and "A" (in this order) into index. Then you will avoid lookup into table for value of "A" when "B" is matched. It is especially helpful if table contains many columns you do not care about.

Comment: A B*tree index would still perform badly in the OP's test case, for the reasons I outlined in my answer.  A covering index would help; but if his test case were more realistic, it wouldn't be necessary / would be a waste of space.  Upvote for pointing out the covering index -- it is a useful technique.  But I just wouldn't want the OP to think he's got to make a covering index just to make indexes "work".